# Search data from database

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, search-engine

[image: database error]

I want to display data from database. I created a search form but there is an error to display the result. Attached screenshot of the error.

In the database, consist of staff name and branch. The branch dropdown list, I get it from the database. Example of branch is Faculty Computer Science and Mathematics.

I think the error is in the model.
Can someone help me to fix my code

**CONTROLLER**

```
   function filter_directory()
  {

  $search_term = $this->input->post('search_term');
  $search_branch = $this->input->post('search_branch');

  $data['search_term'] = $search_term;
  $data['search_branch'] = $search_branch;

  $data['branch_name'] = $this->direktori_model->get_branch_list();

  $data['search_term'] = $this->input->get('search_term');
  $data['search_branch'] =$this->input->get('search_branch');

  $data['results'] = $this->direktori_model->get_directory_results($data['search_term'], $data['search_branch'], $config['per_page'], $page);

  $this->load->view('directory/directory_list', $data);
}
```

**MODEL**

```
function get_directory_results($search_term, $search_branch, $limit=10, $offset=0)
{
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Staff_Profile
    WHERE Name LIKE '%$search_term%' 
    AND Branch = {$search_branch}
    AND Enabled = 'Y' 
    AND Lang ='BM'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    OFFSET {$offset} ROWS
    FETCH NEXT {$limit} ROWS ONlY";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
   }
```

**VIEW**

```
   <?php echo validation_errors();?>
    <?php echo form_open("direktori/filter_directory", array('method' => 'get'));?>
    <div class="row collapse">
      <div class="medium-4 columns ">
        <?php echo form_input(array('name' => 'search_term', 'id' => 'search-box', 'value' => $search_term)); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-4 columns ">
        <?php echo form_dropdown("search_branch", $branch_name, "", 'id="branch_id"');?>
      </div>
      <div class="medium-4  columns ">
      <?php echo form_submit('search', 'SEARCH', 'class="button expand"'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal sorry, i have attached screenshot of the error

Comment: Which db driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you must add quote after BRANCH

Your query:

```
SELECT * FROM staff_profile 
where name Like '%anuar%'
and branch = BAHAGIAN KEWAIGAN & PENGURUSAN  <-- ERROR
and enabled = 'Y' and lang = 'BM'
order by id asc offset o rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Fixed query:

```
SELECT * FROM staff_profile 
where name Like '%anuar%'
and branch = 'BAHAGIAN KEWAIGAN & PENGURUSAN'
and enabled = 'Y' and lang = 'BM'
order by id asc offset o rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Comment: i already tried it,, there is no error as screenshot attached but the result does not show up

Comment: @nienahusain: In your screenshot there's an error (fixed by quote of branch value). If you have not results, please check your data. Post, if possible, an example of your data, so we can analyze them

Answer (score 0):

Error come in near branch. please put branch inside quotes.

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM Staff_Profile
    WHERE Name LIKE '%$search_term%' 
    AND Branch = '$search_branch'
    AND Enabled = 'Y' 
    AND Lang ='BM'
    ORDER BY ID ASC
    OFFSET {$offset} ROWS
    FETCH NEXT {$limit} ROWS ONlY";`

Answer (score 0):

use codeigniter syntax in the model

```
function get_directory_results($search_term, $search_branch, $limit=10, $offset=0){
    $this->db->order_by('ID','ASC');
    $this->db->like('Name',$search_term);
    $this->db->where('Lang','BM');
    $this->db->where('Enabled','Y');
    $this->db->where('Branch',$search_term);
    $query=$this->db->get('Staff_Profile',$limit,$offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

in this format you could port to any other BD and show you more easy the troubles that you have.